# Filtros em arquivo TXT

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, txt

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ud743B57XM_iZ_wvQrSYGRrMo-5nT94p

Tenho um arquivo `txt` que tenho que aplicar um filtro para me trazer um campo na coluna 2. E depois salvar o resultado em `csv`, pois assim fica mais fácil de mexer.

Só que está muito difícil manipular os dados `txt`.  Até agora só conseguir abrir o arquivos sem a linha 1(pois é um cabeçalho inútil).
Utilizei o código:

```
trecho = open('exemplo.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()[1:5]
print(trecho)
```

Conteúdo do arquivo txt:

```
RH NEG                 2018-11-13 2018-11-13 002095584
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000010; 000000000128.950000;000000000000000002;09:52:04.625;1;2018-11-13;000006816341074;000000000513284;2;2018-11-13;000006816341042;000000000513285;2;0;00000088;00001130
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000070; 000000000128.500000;000000000000000001;10:29:29.292;1;2018-11-13;000006816341437;000000000524369;2;2018-11-13;000006816341463;000000000524370;1;0;00000003;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000090; 000000000128.500000;000000000000000001;10:34:28.447;1;2018-11-13;000006816341499;000000000526119;2;2018-11-13;000006816341500;000000000526120;1;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000100; 000000000128.050000;000000000000000001;10:43:51.211;1;2018-11-13;000006816341514;000000000530164;2;2018-11-13;000006816341319;000000000530165;1;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000130; 000000000128.400000;000000000000000001;11:20:18.817;1;2018-11-13;000006816341940;000000000545815;1;2018-11-13;000006816341855;000000000545816;2;0;00000088;00000003
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000150; 000000000127.600000;000000000000000002;11:36:13.283;1;2018-11-13;000006816342069;000000000554070;2;2018-11-13;000006816342139;000000000554071;1;0;00000107;00000003
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000190; 000000000128.000000;000000000000000001;11:51:35.790;1;2018-11-13;000006816342313;000000000559841;1;2018-11-13;000006816342289;000000000559842;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000200; 000000000128.000000;000000000000000001;11:54:43.262;1;2018-11-13;000006816342357;000000000561090;1;2018-11-13;000006816342289;000000000561091;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000210; 000000000127.600000;000000000000000001;12:59:21.065;1;2018-11-13;000006816342824;000000000594427;2;2018-11-13;000006816342851;000000000594428;1;0;00000003;00000088
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000230; 000000000127.400000;000000000000000001;13:01:31.207;1;2018-11-13;000006816340294;000000000595852;2;2018-11-13;000006816342866;000000000595853;1;0;00000003;00000115
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000240; 000000000127.400000;000000000000000001;13:04:39.951;1;2018-11-13;000006816340294;000000000599434;2;2018-11-13;000006816342893;000000000599435;1;0;00000003;00000088
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000250; 000000000127.400000;000000000000000003;13:05:28.547;1;2018-11-13;000006816340294;000000000600457;2;2018-11-13;000006816342872;000000000600458;1;0;00000003;00000115
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000260; 000000000127.400000;000000000000000003;13:05:28.672;1;2018-11-13;000006816340294;000000000600485;2;2018-11-13;000006816342902;000000000600486;1;0;00000003;00000115
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000270; 000000000127.400000;000000000000000003;13:05:28.796;1;2018-11-13;000006816340294;000000000600492;2;2018-11-13;000006816342903;000000000600493;1;0;00000003;00000115
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000280; 000000000127.400000;000000000000000003;13:05:46.409;1;2018-11-13;000006816340294;000000000600796;2;2018-11-13;000006816342913;000000000600797;1;0;00000003;00000088
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000290; 000000000127.400000;000000000000000002;13:06:18.642;1;2018-11-13;000006816340294;000000000601431;2;2018-11-13;000006816342929;000000000601432;1;0;00000003;00000115
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000300; 000000000127.400000;000000000000000014;13:06:46.037;1;2018-11-13;000006816340294;000000000601863;2;2018-11-13;000006816342935;000000000601864;1;0;00000003;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000310; 000000000127.250000;000000000000000001;13:07:57.548;1;2018-11-13;000006816341631;000000000602867;2;2018-11-13;000006816342951;000000000602868;1;0;00000093;00000088
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000320; 000000000127.250000;000000000000000001;13:09:32.861;1;2018-11-13;000006816342972;000000000604269;1;2018-11-13;000006816342952;000000000604270;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000340; 000000000127.000000;000000000000000001;13:15:53.290;1;2018-11-13;000006816340152;000000000607368;2;2018-11-13;000006816343014;000000000607369;1;0;00000107;00000088
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000350; 000000000127.000000;000000000000000002;13:19:50.193;1;2018-11-13;000006816343049;000000000609663;1;2018-11-13;000006816343028;000000000609664;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000360; 000000000127.000000;000000000000000001;13:20:08.604;1;2018-11-13;000006816343051;000000000609944;1;2018-11-13;000006816343028;000000000609945;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000380; 000000000126.850000;000000000000000001;13:21:05.820;1;2018-11-13;000006816340130;000000000610730;2;2018-11-13;000006816343057;000000000610731;1;0;00000003;00000088
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000370; 000000000126.850000;000000000000000001;13:21:05.820;1;2018-11-13;000006816339968;000000000610728;2;2018-11-13;000006816343057;000000000610729;1;0;00000386;00000088
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000390; 000000000127.000000;000000000000000003;13:31:46.062;1;2018-11-13;000006816343123;000000000619774;1;2018-11-13;000006816343028;000000000619775;2;0;00000386;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000420; 000000000126.550000;000000000000000001;13:50:05.252;1;2018-11-13;000006816343212;000000000626737;2;2018-11-13;000006816343285;000000000626738;1;0;00000088;00000386
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000430; 000000000126.550000;000000000000000001;13:50:05.252;1;2018-11-13;000006816343055;000000000626739;2;2018-11-13;000006816343285;000000000626740;1;0;00000093;00000386
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000450; 000000000127.000000;000000000000000002;14:02:05.847;1;2018-11-13;000006816343394;000000000628566;1;2018-11-13;000006816343028;000000000628567;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000540; 000000000126.300000;000000000000000001;14:30:28.815;1;2018-11-13;000006816343723;000000000635848;1;2018-11-13;000006816343718;000000000635849;2;0;00000088;00000115
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000550; 000000000126.000000;000000000000000001;14:34:55.147;1;2018-11-13;000006816343326;000000000637084;2;2018-11-13;000006816343784;000000000637085;1;0;00000107;00000088
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000560; 000000000126.000000;000000000000000001;14:41:05.046;1;2018-11-13;000006816343815;000000000638801;2;2018-11-13;000006816343127;000000000638802;1;0;00000088;00000003
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000580; 000000000126.300000;000000000000000004;14:47:21.562;1;2018-11-13;000006816343899;000000000640855;1;2018-11-13;000006816343761;000000000640856;2;0;00000088;00000003
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000590; 000000000126.300000;000000000000000001;14:54:09.132;1;2018-11-13;000006816343951;000000000642905;1;2018-11-13;000006816343946;000000000642906;2;0;00000088;00000003
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000600; 000000000126.400000;000000000000000002;14:59:10.618;1;2018-11-13;000006816343989;000000000644134;1;2018-11-13;000006816343728;000000000644135;2;0;00000088;00000003
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000610; 000000000126.400000;000000000000000001;15:20:17.042;1;2018-11-13;000006816344163;000000000649842;1;2018-11-13;000006816343728;000000000649843;2;0;00000088;00000003
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000630; 000000000126.500000;000000000000000001;15:21:55.894;1;2018-11-13;000006816344179;000000000650262;1;2018-11-13;000006816343736;000000000650263;2;0;00000088;00000003
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000640; 000000000126.500000;000000000000000001;15:21:56.494;1;2018-11-13;000006816344180;000000000650266;1;2018-11-13;000006816343736;000000000650267;2;0;00000088;00000003
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000650; 000000000126.500000;000000000000000001;15:23:04.480;1;2018-11-13;000006816344191;000000000650624;2;2018-11-13;000006816344194;000000000650625;1;0;00000107;00000088
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000690; 000000000127.000000;000000000000000002;16:16:38.956;1;2018-11-13;000006816344708;000000000679240;1;2018-11-13;000006816343028;000000000679241;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000870; 000000000127.000000;000000000000000002;16:18:50.473;1;2018-11-13;000006816344803;000000000681511;1;2018-11-13;000006816343028;000000000681512;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000880; 000000000127.000000;000000000000000001;16:22:50.396;1;2018-11-13;000006816344725;000000000684797;1;2018-11-13;000006816343028;000000000684798;2;0;00000107;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000900; 000000000127.000000;000000000000000001;16:22:55.429;1;2018-11-13;000006816344991;000000000684858;1;2018-11-13;000006816343028;000000000684859;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000890; 000000000127.000000;000000000000000001;16:22:55.429;1;2018-11-13;000006816344991;000000000684856;1;2018-11-13;000006816343028;000000000684857;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000910; 000000000127.000000;000000000000000002;16:25:58.087;1;2018-11-13;000006816345164;000000000687581;1;2018-11-13;000006816343028;000000000687582;2;0;00000107;00000107
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000140; 000000000036.690000;000000000000000001;09:00:30.000;1;2018-11-13;000006816339990;000000000501806;2;2018-11-13;000006816339872;000000000501807;2;0;00000115;00000003
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000150; 000000000036.660000;000000000000000001;09:03:24.556;1;2018-11-13;000006816339870;000000000502280;2;2018-11-13;000006816340183;000000000502281;1;0;00000003;00000003
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000180; 000000000036.650000;000000000000000005;09:04:01.483;1;2018-11-13;000006816340201;000000000502377;1;2018-11-13;000006816340183;000000000502378;2;0;00000115;00000003
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000190; 000000000036.650000;000000000000000001;09:06:31.695;1;2018-11-13;000006816340240;000000000502767;1;2018-11-13;000006816340183;000000000502768;2;0;00000003;00000003
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000200; 000000000036.700000;000000000000000002;09:10:22.489;1;2018-11-13;000006816340273;000000000503320;1;2018-11-13;000006816339869;000000000503321;2;0;00000003;00000386
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000210; 000000000036.750000;000000000000000002;09:13:31.894;1;2018-11-13;000006816340301;000000000503716;1;2018-11-13;000006816340285;000000000503717;2;0;00000093;00000010
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000220; 000000000036.750000;000000000000000001;09:15:54.127;1;2018-11-13;000006816340337;000000000504224;1;2018-11-13;000006816340306;000000000504225;2;0;00000093;00000115
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000260; 000000000036.800000;000000000000000002;09:18:40.400;1;2018-11-13;000006816340391;000000000505101;1;2018-11-13;000006816339938;000000000505102;2;0;00000115;00000010
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000250; 000000000036.800000;000000000000000003;09:18:40.400;1;2018-11-13;000006816340391;000000000505099;1;2018-11-13;000006816339884;000000000505100;2;0;00000115;00000115
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000270; 000000000036.790000;000000000000000002;09:18:54.521;1;2018-11-13;000006816340395;000000000505157;1;2018-11-13;000006816340394;000000000505158;2;0;00000115;00000003
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000290; 000000000036.830000;000000000000000001;09:21:11.606;1;2018-11-13;000006816340438;000000000505762;1;2018-11-13;000006816340436;000000000505763;2;0;00000003;00000010
2018-11-13;CCMX18                                            ;0000000520; 000000000036.800000;000000000000000006;09:39:34.837;1;2018-11-13;000006816340915;000000000510252;1;2018-11-13;000006816340559;000000000510253;2;0;00000003;00000058
```

Obs: No resultado, o delimitador de linhas é ', e o delimitador de colunas é ;.  Porém só quando jogo o código, que da pra ver o delimitador de linhas '.

Comment: Que tipo de filtro você precisa fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-filtering-by-substring)**
Se entendi corretamente, vc quer ler o arquivo e depois selecionar linhas em que apareça determinada palavra em uma determina coluna. Peguei uma parte do texto que vc colocou na pergunta coloquei a palavra **stackoverflow** em 3 linhas da coluna 1 (segunda coluna) para usar no filtro, vamos considerar esse trecho  como sendo nosso arquvivo `csv`. Tanto para ler como para filtrar vamos utilizar o [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
import io
import pandas as pd

csv = '''
RH NEG                 2018-11-13 2018-11-13 002095584
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000010; 000000000128.950000;000000000000000002;09:52:04.625;1;2018-11-13;000006816341074;000000000513284;2;2018-11-13;000006816341042;000000000513285;2;0;00000088;00001130
2018-11-13;stackoverflow                                            ;0000000070; 000000000128.500000;000000000000000001;10:29:29.292;1;2018-11-13;000006816341437;000000000524369;2;2018-11-13;000006816341463;000000000524370;1;0;00000003;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000090; 000000000128.500000;000000000000000001;10:34:28.447;1;2018-11-13;000006816341499;000000000526119;2;2018-11-13;000006816341500;000000000526120;1;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000100; 000000000128.050000;000000000000000001;10:43:51.211;1;2018-11-13;000006816341514;000000000530164;2;2018-11-13;000006816341319;000000000530165;1;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000130; 000000000128.400000;000000000000000001;11:20:18.817;1;2018-11-13;000006816341940;000000000545815;1;2018-11-13;000006816341855;000000000545816;2;0;00000088;00000003
2018-11-13;stackoverflow                                            ;0000000150; 000000000127.600000;000000000000000002;11:36:13.283;1;2018-11-13;000006816342069;000000000554070;2;2018-11-13;000006816342139;000000000554071;1;0;00000107;00000003
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000190; 000000000128.000000;000000000000000001;11:51:35.790;1;2018-11-13;000006816342313;000000000559841;1;2018-11-13;000006816342289;000000000559842;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000200; 000000000128.000000;000000000000000001;11:54:43.262;1;2018-11-13;000006816342357;000000000561090;1;2018-11-13;000006816342289;000000000561091;2;0;00000088;00000107
2018-11-13;stackoverflow                                            ;0000000210; 000000000127.600000;000000000000000001;12:59:21.065;1;2018-11-13;000006816342824;000000000594427;2;2018-11-13;000006816342851;000000000594428;1;0;00000003;00000088
2018-11-13;heberteste                                            ;0000000230; 000000000127.400000;000000000000000001;13:01:31.207;1;2018-11-13;000006816340294;000000000595852;2;2018-11-13;000006816342866;000000000595853;1;0;00000003;00000115
'''

# Lendo o csv 
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), skiprows=[0], sep=';', header=None)

# Apresentand o df
print(df)
```

Saída (Fragmento):

```
           0                                                  1    2       3   \
0  2018-11-13  heberteste                                    ...   10  128.95   
1  2018-11-13  stackoverflow                                 ...   70  128.50   
2  2018-11-13  heberteste                                    ...   90  128.50   
3  2018-11-13  heberteste                                    ...  100  128.05   
4  2018-11-13  heberteste                                    ...  130  128.40   
5  2018-11-13  stackoverflow                                 ...  150  127.60   
.....
```

Agora vamos criar um novo `DataFrame` somente com as linhas em que a palavra "stackoverflow" apareça. `

```
# Filtrando
s = 'stackoverflow'
df_filtered = df[df[1].str.contains(s)]

# Apresentado o resultado
print(df_filtered)
```

Usamos `contains` aqui por que na segunda coluna tem uma grande quantidade de espaços, mas poderia ser tb uma igualdade absoluta, por exemplo `df[df[1]==s]`

Saída (Fragmento):

```
           0                                                  1    2      3   \
1  2018-11-13  stackoverflow                                 ...   70  128.5   
5  2018-11-13  stackoverflow                                 ...  150  127.6   
8  2018-11-13  stackoverflow                                 ...  210  127.6
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-filtering-by-substring)

Comment: Oi Sidon, muitíssimo obrigado, ficou excelente essa explicação. Porém o meu arquivo é em TXT,  teria que pelo menos passar ele para csv? Eu coloquei um link do arquivo em anexo.  Se não for abusar, consegue me ajudar se baseando no arquivo txt.  Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade um arquivo `.csv` é um arquivo do tipo `txt` com uma formatação especifica, então vc não precisa fazer nada. Peguei seu texto e fiz um teste, notei que cometi um erro na leitura do arquivo, ja corrigi na resposta e no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-filtering-by-substring). Mude o comando de leitura do arquivo de `df = pd.read_csv(txt, skiprows=[1],  sep=';', header=None)` para `df = pd.read_csv(txt, skiprows=[0],  sep=';', header=None)`  e faça o teste novamente.

Comment: Se ficou obscuro para vc percber o que mudou, preste atenção em `skiprows[1]` para `skiprows[0]` eu estava ignorando a segunda linha do arquivo, mas a linha que tem q ser ignorada é a primeira, que foge do padrão das outras.

Comment: Oi Boa noite.  Nossa, agora deu certo. Muito obrigado. Abs

Comment: Fico feliz de saber que deu certo, considere dar o aceite na resposta (Tick verde proximo as setas de votação) :-)